# set default application/program priority in Linux

Tags: linux

How do I set default priority of a specific application/program for any user which runs under the priority what we set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the program into a shell script and let your users run it instead of the original program:

```
#!/bin/sh
nice -10 path/to/the/program/executable "$@"
```

Comment: make it `nice -10 path/to/the/program/executable "$@"` so you don't drop arguments